# How Best To Buffer This Incoming UART Data

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I need to receive a six-byte packet via the UART (using an STM32L010F4). There is a SOF and an EOF byte included in these six bytes. There could be long stretches when no data is sent, followed by a stream of these six-byte packets that are 5mS apart. Once a valid packet is received, I need to perform some basic math on the four non-SOF/EOF bytes (some addition and multiplication), re-package the data into another packet, and send it out to a host on a different UART.

Utilizing the DMA seems to cause me to miss-sync with these incoming messages, as has been pointed out to me. What would be the best architecture for this? Utilize a much larger buffer?

EDIT: I implemented pmacfarlane's solution below and it is working fairly well. The issue I am having is if there is a series a packets (let's say a dozen), I don't transmit the LAST packet. It's sitting in the RX buffer, but the head and tail indices are equal, so never gets processed/sent. The reason the indices are equal is because after receiving the SOF and four data bytes within my UART ISR, I do NOT receive the EOF byte (which is where the head index actually gets incremented). I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I set a counter within the state machine inside the UART RX ISR to indicate when the data buffer is full. I then set a flag in the RX callback indicating the full buffer, but despite calling for one more byte, the IRQ doesn't fire. The breakpoit is never hit.

I only know it's the "last" packet in the series because the SOF byte is slightly different than the others, so I can look for it.

The RX callback:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(RX_Pkt == 4)
    {
        DataFull = TRUE;  //Full data buffer flag
    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT( &huart2, RX_Touch_Data, 1 );                       
}

void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint8_t Curr_Byte = *huart2.pRxBuffPtr;

    if(DataFull == TRUE)
    {
        DataFull = FALSE;  //Breakpoint here not hit
    }

    switch(Pkt_State)
    {
        case STATE_WAIT_SOF:
        {
            Data_Indx = 0;

            if( Curr_Byte == EETI_TD_PKT)
            {
                Msg_Buff[Buff_Head_Indx].RX_Data[Data_Indx] = Curr_Byte;                
                ++Data_Indx;
                Pkt_State = STATE_RX_DATA;
            }
        }
        break;

        case STATE_RX_DATA:
        {
            Msg_Buff[Buff_Head_Indx].RX_Data[Data_Indx] = Curr_Byte;
            ++Data_Indx;

            if( Data_Indx == DATA_SIZE )
            {
                 Pkt_State = STATE_WAIT_EOF;
            }

            if (Msg_Buff[Buff_Head_Indx].RX_Data[0] == SPECIAL_PKT)
            {
                 RX_Pkt++;     //Test code looking for full data buffer
            }
        }
        break;
```

I am 100% confident the source of the data is sending the EOF packet; I have confirmed with a RS-232 snooper. I can't understand why this last byte isn't registering. What makes it more interesting is the NEXT time I activate the device the send a series of packets, it "forces" the old packet out. So if I send ten groups of a dozen packets, I get a dozen for the first nine, then only eleven packets for the 12th (though again, in examining the buffer, the data is there). If I ony send ONE burst, I only ever get eleven and don't receieve the 12th.

Comment: Can your SOF/EOF bytes occur as part of the 4 other data bytes? i.e. could any of the 4 data bytes have the same value as SOF/EOF?

Comment: @pmacfarlane - Good question. No, they cannot. They are unique from any possibe data.

Comment: use also IDLE interrupt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using an ISR to handle each character that is received by the UART, and maintaining a state machine indicating the current reception status (e.g. waiting for SOF, reading data, waiting for EOF). This has the advantage that it will naturally re-synchronise with the data stream if it is ever interrupted, which is hard to do if you are DMAing fixed sized blobs of data and hoping they are aligned.

I'd also maintain a circular buffer of received messages, which the ISR is writing into. I'd then have my main "thread" loop reading messages out of this queue, processing them, and sending responses. This means that if a bunch of messages come in really quickly, and the processing can't keep up, you won't lose any.

Some commented (untested) code that hopefully shows the idea:

```c
#define DATA_SIZE    4u   // How many bytes in each message
#define NUM_MESSAGES 32u  // How many messages can be in the queue

enum state_e {
    STATE_WAIT_FOR_SOF,
    STATE_DATA,
    STATE_WAIT_FOR_EOF
};

struct message {
    uint8_t data[DATA_SIZE];
};

// A circular buffer of messages
// Volatile since the ISR modifies them. (Probably not necessary, but harmless)
static volatile struct message msgs[NUM_MESSAGES];

// The index for the next entry to be written
// Volatile since the ISR can modify it
static volatile uint8_t head_ix = 0u;

// The index for the next entry to read
static uint8_t tail_ix = 0u;

// Start off waiting for SOF
static enum state_e state = STATE_WAIT_FOR_SOF;

// An index into the current message (being written)'s data[] array
static uint8_t data_ix;

static void process_msg(struct message *msg)
{
    // Process msg and send response
}

int main(void)
{
    // Any other initialisation happens...
  
    while (1)
    {
        // Any messages in the queue? Queue is empty if head_ix == tail_ix.
        if (tail_ix != head_ix)
        {
            // Consume a message
            process_message(&msgs[tail_ix]);
            tail_ix = (tail_ix + 1u) % NUM_MESSAGES;
        }
    }
}

// A ficticious interrupt handler that deals with a single character.
// Your real implementation will have to deal with reading the character
// from the UART, clearing the interrupt, etc, then call something like this.
void handle_rx_interrupt(uint8_t datum)
{
    switch (state)
    {
    case STATE_WAIT_FOR_SOF:
        if (datum == SOF)
        {
            // Got SOF, move to data state
            state = STATE_DATA;

            // Waiting for the first byte of data
            data_ix = 0u;
        }
        break;

    case STATE_DATA:
        // Store this datum in the message
        msgs[head_ix].data[data_ix] = datum;
        ++data_ix;

        // If we have a full message, move to waiting for EOF state
        if (data_ix == DATA_SIZE)
        {
            state = STATE_WAIT_FOR_EOF;
        }
        break;

    case STATE_WAIT_FOR_EOF:
        if (datum == EOF)
        {
            // See if we have space in the queue for this message
            uint8_t new_head = (head_ix + 1u) % NUM_MESSAGES;

            if (new_head != tail_ix)
            {
                // Yes, add this message
                head_ix = new_head;
            }
            else
            {
                // No space for this message. It will just be overwritten
                // in place by the next message
            }
        }

        // No matter what happened, we're now waiting for SOF
        state = STATE_WAIT_FOR_SOF;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that in reality there can only ever be `NUM_MESSAGES - 1` entries in the queue, due to how the full/empty condition works. The alternative (to reclaim the "wasted" entry) involves things like disabling interrupts in certain places etc, and adds more work for little gain.

Comment: Took me a bit to get back to this, but got the chance to implement the idea today. It's working great. Much better than waiting for a chunk of data via DMA like you said (especially as the app doesn't really have anything to do if there's no data). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of room in the comments so edited my original question.

Comment: You seem to be doing things a bit oddly. I'm not sure why you're calling `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` at all, and it seems like you're using both the HAL ISR and a "raw" ISR. You should ditch the HAL for receiving this data. I don't know if adding things to this question is the best way forward.

Comment: Specifically, it seems like you might be receiving a byte from the UART and storing it in `*huart2.pRxBuffPtr` on one interrupt, and then only reading that out and processing on the _next_ interrupt. You're always one byte behind, from what I can tell.

Comment: It's fine to use the HAL to initialise the UART. But don't use it to process interrupts or kick off a receive. Write your own ISR, and enable the receiver and receive interrupt yourself. Then you'll always have the latest byte.

Comment: Can you expand more on "always one byte behind"? When the IRQ fires, I capture the latest byte in the UART RX buff as "Curr_Byte". I then go through the state machine, and based on state decide if it's a SOF, data, or EOF. Am I missing something fundamental? Also not sure about "not sure why you're calling HAL_UART_Receive_IT() at all"? How else do I receive the next byte from the UART? It is odd to have both the raw IRQ AND an RX Callback; this was a vestige from when I was capturing bulk data using the DMA and wanted to use the Half Complete interrupt. I will correct this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a basic buffer handling data structure: a pointer to a buffer (or buffer array) and an index.

```
typedef struct{
  int8_t* RxBuffer;
  volatile uint8_t RxFirstEmptyIndex;
  uint8_t RxBufferMaxLength;
}UART_RxBufferHandle;
```

Allocate some memory for RxBuffer (malloc or anything else), put max length into the appropriate variable.

Upon data received interrupt, you read UART data register into RxBuffer[RxFirstEmptyIndex], then increment RxFirstEmptyIndex by 1. If it reaches MaxLength (end of buffer), you need to handle it (otherwise USART peripheral will have overrun error and will refuse to work until you resolve it - read incoming data and clear error flag). After receiving N characters you can handle the input (for example, after receiving 6 characters - when RxFirstEmptyIndex becomes 6), and reset RxFirstEmptyIndex back to 0; Volatile because its value is changes in an interrupt.

You can create a global variable from the struct to make it visible for the interrupt handler. Or find some other solution for it.

You can utilize more or less similar mechanisms for other protocols and communications by adding/changing variables in such a struct. But buffer handling usually happens similar to this. Obviously, if you feel like 256 characters is too little, you're welcome to change index counter and length to uint16_t or uint32_t.